# Best Logic to Print Prime Numbers with SQL query

Tags: sql, select, subquery

What is the most efficient way to get prime numbers from 2 to 1000 via SQL in MongoDB/MySQL/CockroachDB?

My query in Oracle:

```
WITH NUM AS (
    SELECT LEVEL N 
    FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
) 
SELECT LISTAGG(B.N,'-') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY B.N) AS PRIMES 
FROM (
    SELECT  N,
            CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                                SELECT NULL 
                                FROM NUM N_INNER 
                                WHERE N_INNER .N > 1 
                                AND N_INNER.N < NUM.N 
                                AND MOD(NUM.N, N_INNER.N)=0
                            ) THEN 
                'NO PRIME' 
            ELSE 
                'PRIME' 
            END IS_PRIME 
        FROM NUM
    ) B 
WHERE B.IS_PRIME='PRIME' 
AND B.N!=1;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to achieve? The query that you presented is `Oracle` specific. Do you need equivalents in other RDBMS or better algorithm to get primes?

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. "most efficient" doesn't mean anything in particular. After you define it, where/how are you stuck achieving it? What does your code have to do with the rest of your post. What was your actual assignment? Why are you mentioning all of Oracle/MongoDB/MySQL/CockroachDB? Pick one. [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PostgreSQL probably the most fastest query that prints prime numbers up to 1000 is:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541,547,557,563,569,571,577,587,593,599,601,607,613,617,619,631,641,643,647,653,659,661,673,677,683,691,701,709,719,727,733,739,743,751,757,761,769,773,787,797,809,811,821,823,827,829,839,853,857,859,863,877,881,883,887,907,911,919,929,937,941,947,953,967,971,977,983,991,997',E',')::int
AS x
;
```

It took only 16 ms on my computer.

- Note: a list of prime numbers was copied from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number

  and pasted into this long string

---

If you prefer SQL, then this works

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT * FROM generate_series( 2, 1000 ) x
)
SELECT x.x
FROM x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM x y
  WHERE x.x > y.x AND x.x % y.x = 0
)
;
```

It's two times slower - 31 ms.

---

Ans an equivalent version for Oracle:

```
WITH x AS(
    SELECT level+1 x
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 999
)
SELECT x.x
FROM x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM x y
  WHERE x.x > y.x AND remainder( x.x, y.x) = 0
)
;
```

Comment: You can halve the time using only 2 and odds: `SELECT 2 x UNION ALL SELECT * FROM generate_series(3, 1000, 2) x`

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious improvement is that instead of checking from 1 to n you can check from 1 to the square root of n.

A second major optimization would be to use a temporary table to store the results and check them first.  This way you can iterate incrementally from 1 to n, and only check the known primes from 1 to square root of n (recursively doing that until you have a list).  If you go about things this way you would probably want to set up the prime detection in a function and then do the same with your number series generator.

That second one though means extending SQL and so I don't know if that fits your requirements.

For postgresql I would use `generate_series` go generate the list of numbers.  I would then create functions which would then either store the list of primes in a temporary table or pass them back in and out in an ordered array and then couple them like that

Answer (score 2):

**MariaDB (with sequence plugin)**

Similar to kordirkos algorithm:

```sql
select 2 as p union all
select n.seq
from seq_3_to_1000_step_2 n
where not exists (
    select 1
    from seq_3_to_32_step_2 q
    where q.seq < n.seq
      and n.seq mod q.seq = 0
);
```

Using LEFT JOIN:

```sql
select 2 as p union all
select n.seq
from seq_3_to_1000_step_2 n
left join seq_3_to_32_step_2 q
      on  q.seq < n.seq
      and n.seq mod q.seq = 0
where q.seq is null;
```

**MySQL**

There are no sequence generating helpers in MySQL. So the sequence tables have to be created first:

```sql
drop temporary table if exists n;
create temporary table if not exists n engine=memory
    select t2.c*100 + t1.c*10 + t0.c + 1 as seq from 
    (select 0 c union all select 1 c union all select 2 c union all select 3 c union all select 4 c union all select 5 c union all select 6 c union all select 7 c union all select 8 c union all select 9 c) t0,
    (select 0 c union all select 1 c union all select 2 c union all select 3 c union all select 4 c union all select 5 c union all select 6 c union all select 7 c union all select 8 c union all select 9 c) t1,
    (select 0 c union all select 1 c union all select 2 c union all select 3 c union all select 4 c union all select 5 c union all select 6 c union all select 7 c union all select 8 c union all select 9 c) t2
    having seq > 2 and seq % 2 != 0;

drop temporary table if exists q;
create temporary table if not exists q engine=memory
    select *
    from n
    where seq <= 32;
alter table q add primary key seq (seq);
```

Now similar queries can be used:

```sql
select 2 as p union all
select n.seq
from n
where not exists (
    select 1
    from q
    where q.seq < n.seq
      and n.seq mod q.seq = 0
);

select 2 as p union all
select n.seq
from n
left join q
    on  q.seq < n.seq
    and n.seq mod q.seq = 0
where q.seq is null;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57d11/3)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle and without inner select in getting part:

```
 with tmp(id)
as (
    select level  id from dual connect by level <= 100 
) select t1.id from tmp t1
 JOIN tmp t2
 on MOD(t1.id, t2.id) = 0
 group by t1.ID
 having count(t1.id) = 2
 order by t1.ID
 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Step 1: Get all the numbers till 1000 */

with tempa as
(
  select level as Num
  from dual
  connect by level<=1000
),

/* Step 2: Get the Numbers for finding out the factors */

tempb as
(
    select a.NUm, b.Num as Num_1
    from tempa a , tempa b
    where b.Num<=a.Num
),

/*Step 3: If a number has exactly 2 factors, then it is a prime number */

tempc as
(
    select Num, sum(case when mod(num,num_1)=0 then 1 end) as Factor_COunt
    from tempb
    group by Num
)
select listagg(Num,'&') within group (order by Num)
from tempc
where Factor_COunt=2
;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(NUMB SEPARATOR '&')
FROM (
    SELECT @num:=@num+1 as NUMB FROM
    information_schema.tables t1,
    information_schema.tables t2,
    (SELECT @num:=1) tmp
) tempNum
WHERE NUMB<=1000 AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT @nu:=@nu+1 as NUMA FROM
                information_schema.tables t1,
                information_schema.tables t2,
                (SELECT @nu:=1) tmp1
                LIMIT 1000
            ) tatata
        WHERE FLOOR(NUMB/NUMA)=(NUMB/NUMA) AND NUMA<NUMB AND NUMA>1
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested on sqlite3

```
WITH nums(n) AS 
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM nums WHERE n < 100
)

SELECT n 
FROM (
  SELECT n FROM nums
) 
WHERE n NOT IN (
  SELECT n
  FROM nums 
  JOIN ( SELECT n AS n2 FROM nums )
  WHERE n  <> 1 
    AND n2 <> 1 
    AND n  <> n2 
    AND n2 <  n 
    AND n % n2 = 0
  ORDER BY n
)
AND n <> 1
```

Tested on Vertica 8

```
WITH seq AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS n 
  FROM (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM (
          SELECT date(0) + INTERVAL '1 second' AS i 
          UNION ALL
          SELECT date(0) + INTERVAL '100 seconds' AS i 
      ) _
      TIMESERIES tm AS '1 second' OVER(ORDER BY i)
  ) _
)
SELECT n 
FROM (SELECT n FROM seq) _  
WHERE n NOT IN (
  SELECT n FROM (
    SELECT s1.n AS n, s2.n AS n2
    FROM seq AS s1 
    CROSS JOIN seq AS s2
    ORDER BY n, n2
  ) _
  WHERE n  <> 1 
    AND n2 <> 1 
    AND n  <> n2 
    AND n2 <  n 
    AND n % n2 = 0
)
AND n <> 1
ORDER BY n
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked in SQL Server. I reduce the order of nested loops.

```
declare @var int
declare @i int
declare @result varchar (max)
set @var = 1
select @result = '2&3&5' --first few obvious prime numbers
while @var < 1000  --the first loop
begin
set @i = 3;
while @i <= @var/2  --the second loop which I attempted to reduce the order
begin
if @var%@i = 0
break;
if @i=@var/2 
begin
set @result = @result + '&' + CAST(@var AS VARCHAR)
break;
end
else 
set @i = @i + 1 
end
set @var = @var + 1;
end
print @result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LISTAGG(PRIME_NUMBER,'&') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PRIME_NUMBER) 
FROM
(
    SELECT L PRIME_NUMBER FROM
    (
        SELECT LEVEL L FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000 ), 
        (
            SELECT LEVEL M FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
        ) WHERE M <= L 
        GROUP BY L 
        HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN L/M = TRUNC(L/M) THEN 'Y' END
    ) = 2 
    ORDER BY L
);
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Code :

```
DECLARE 
@i INT, 
@a INT, 
@count INT, 
@p nvarchar(max)
SET @i = 1 
WHILE (@i <= 1000) 
BEGIN SET @count = 0 
SET @a = 1 
WHILE (@a <= @i) 
BEGIN IF (@i % @a = 0) SET @count = @count + 1 SET @a = @a + 1 
END IF (@count = 2) SET @P = CONCAT(@P,CONCAT(@i,'&')) SET @i = @i + 1 
END
PRINT LEFT(@P, LEN(@P) - 1)
```

Comment: The OP is looking for a solution which is more efficient than the code they currently have in their question. Can you explain a bit more about what exactly your code is doing and where its improvements come from?

Answer (score 0):

The below code works to find prime numbers in SQL

Tested on SampleDB of local server

```
CREATE procedure sp_PrimeNumber(@number int)
as 
begin
declare @i int
declare @j int
declare @isPrime int
set @isPrime=1
set @i=2
set @j=2
while(@i<=@number)
begin
    while(@j<=@number)
    begin
        if((@i<>@j) and (@i%@j=0))
        begin
            set @isPrime=0
            break
        end
        else
        begin
            set @j=@j+1
        end
    end
    if(@isPrime=1)
    begin
        SELECT @i
    end
    set @isPrime=1
    set @i=@i+1
    set @j=2
end
end
```

I have created the stored procedure which has a parameter @number to find the prime numbers up to that given number

In order to get the prime numbers we can execute the below stored procedure

```
EXECUTE sp_PrimeNumber 100  -- gives prime numbers up to 100
```

If you are new to stored procedures and want to find the prime numbers in SQL we can use the below code

Tested on master DB

```
declare @i int
declare @j int
declare @isPrime int
set @isPrime=1
set @i=2
set @j=2
while(@i<=100)
begin
    while(@j<=100)
    begin
        if((@i<>@j) and (@i%@j=0))
        begin
            set @isPrime=0
            break
        end
        else
        begin
            set @j=@j+1
        end
    end
    if(@isPrime=1)
    begin
        SELECT @i
    end
    set @isPrime=1
    set @i=@i+1
    set @j=2
end
```

This code can give the prime numbers between 1 to 100. If we want to find more prime numbers edit the @i and @j arguments in the while loop and execute

Comment: In SSMS we can execute the stored procedure and then execute it with the arguments required to get the required result

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT serA.el AS prime
FROM generate_series(2, 100) serA(el)
LEFT JOIN generate_series(2, 100) serB(el) ON serA.el >= POWER(serB.el, 2)
                                              AND serA.el % serB.el = 0
WHERE serB.el IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For SQL Server We can use below CTE 

SET NOCOUNT ON

;WITH Prim AS
(
    SELECT 2 AS Value 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Value+1 AS VAlue 
    FROM Prim t
    WHERE t.Value < 1000
)SELECT * 
FROM Prim t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(   SELECT 1 FROM prim t2
                WHERE t.Value % t2.Value = 0 
                AND t.Value != t2. Value)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select level id1 from dual connect by level < 2001
minus
select distinct id1 from (select level id1 from dual connect by level < 46) t1 inner join (select level id2 from dual connect by level < 11) t2
on 1=1 where t1.id1> t2.id2 and mod(id1,id2)=0 and id2<>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method For SQL Server

```
DECLARE @range int = 1000, @x INT = 2, @y INT = 2 

While (@y <= @range)
BEGIN
 while (@x <= @y) 
 begin
    IF ((@y%@x) =0) 
    BEGIN
        IF (@x = @y) 
            PRINT @y
            break
    END
 IF ((@y%@x)<>0)   
 set @x = @x+1
 end  
set @x = 2
set @y = @y+1 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
SET @range = 1000;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(R2.n SEPARATOR '&')
FROM (
        SELECT @ctr2:=@ctr2+1 "n"
        FROM information_schema.tables R2IS1,
        information_schema.tables R2IS2,
        (SELECT @ctr2:=1) TI
        WHERE @ctr2<@range
     ) R2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT R1.n
                FROM (
                    SELECT @ctr1:=@ctr1+1 "n"
                    FROM information_schema.tables R1IS1,
                    information_schema.tables R1IS2,
                    (SELECT @ctr1:=1) I1
                    WHERE @ctr1<@range
                ) R1
                WHERE R2.n%R1.n=0 AND R2.n>R1.n
        )
```

The number of `information_schema.tables` should be increased for more range--e.g. if range is 100000 set the info tables by checking yourself.

Comment: Reading & assigning the same user variable in the same select statement is explicitly undefined in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table prime_number_t (
    integervalue_c integer not null primary key
);

INSERT ALL
    into prime_number_t(integervalue_c) values (1)
    into prime_number_t(integervalue_c) values (2)
    into prime_number_t(integervalue_c) values (3)
    into prime_number_t(integervalue_c) values (4)
    into prime_number_t(integervalue_c) values (5)
    into prime_number_t(integervalue_c) values (6)
    into prime_number_t(integervalue_c) values (7)
    into prime_number_t(integervalue_c) values (8)
    into prime_number_t(integervalue_c) values (9)
    into prime_number_t(integervalue_c) values(10)   
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

COMMIT;
```

Determine which of the below numbers are prime numbers. Same query works for REMAINDER function instead of MOD function.

```
WITH cte_prime_number_t AS
(
select integervalue_c
from prime_number_t
order by integervalue_c
),
cte_maxval AS
(
select max(integervalue_c) AS maxval FROM cte_prime_number_t
),
cte_level AS
(
select LEVEL+1 as lvl
from dual,
cte_maxval
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= cte_maxval.maxval
)
SELECT DISTINCT cpnt.integervalue_c as PrimeNumbers
FROM cte_prime_number_t cpnt
inner join cte_level cl on lvl <= (SELECT maxval FROM cte_maxval)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM cte_level cpn
  WHERE cpnt.integervalue_c > cpn.lvl AND mod(cpnt.integervalue_c,cpn.lvl) = 0
)
order by PrimeNumbers;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in MySql:

```
select '2&3&5&7&11&13&17&19&23&29&31&37&41&43&47&53&59&61&67&71&73&79&83&89&97&101&103&107&109&113&127&131&137&139&149&151&157&163&167&173&179&181&191&193&197&199&211&223&227&229&233&239&241&251&257&263&269&271&277&281&283&293&307&311&313&317&331&337&347&349&353&359&367&373&379&383&389&397&401&409&419&421&431&433&439&443&449&457&461&463&467&479&487&491&499&503&509&521&523&541&547&557&563&569&571&577&587&593&599&601&607&613&617&619&631&641&643&647&653&659&661&673&677&683&691&701&709&719&727&733&739&743&751&757&761&769&773&787&797&809&811&821&823&827&829&839&853&857&859&863&877&881&883&887&907&911&919&929&937&941&947&953&967&971&977&983&991&997';
```

Well, I know the above one is just hardcoded and you will be able to run the problem but it's not what we should go for as a programmer so here is my solution for oracle:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(L1,'&') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY L1) FROM (Select L1 FROM (SELECT LEVEL L1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=1000) Where L1 <> 1 MINUS select L1 from (SELECT LEVEL L1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=1000) A , (SELECT LEVEL L2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=1000) B Where L2<=L1 and MOD(L1,L2)=0 AND L1<>L2 AND L2<>1);
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve the problem as OP wants to create this using SQL code computationally and not by hard coding in a print statement.

Answer (score 0):

**For MySQL 8 or above**

```
/* create a table with one row and that starts with  2 ends at 1000*/

SET cte_max_recursion_depth = 1001; /* works for MySQL 8.0*/
;WITH RECURSIVE sequence AS (
    SELECT 1 AS l
    UNION ALL
    SELECT l + 1 AS value
    FROM sequence
    WHERE sequence.l < 1000
),

/* create a caretesian product of a number to other numbers uptil this very number
so for example if there is a value 5 in a row then it creates these rows using the table below
(5,2), (5,3), (5,4), (5,5) */

J as (
SELECT (a.l) as m  , (b.l) as n 
FROM sequence a, sequence b
WHERE b.l <= a.l)
,

/*take a row from column 1 then divide it with other column values but group by column 1 first,
note the completely divisible count*/
f as 
( SELECT m , SUM(CASE WHEN mod(m,n) = 0 THEN 1  END) as fact
FROM  J 
GROUP BY m
HAVING fact = 2
ORDER BY m ASC /*this view return numbers in descending order so had to use order by*/
)

/* this is for string formatting, converting a column to a string with separator &*/
SELECT group_concat(m SEPARATOR '&') FROM f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked in Oracle:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(a,'&')
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a) 
FROM(WITH x AS(
    SELECT level+1 x
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 999
)

SELECT x.x as a
FROM x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM x y
  WHERE x.x > y.x AND remainder( x.x, y.x) = 0
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(distinct PRIME_NUMBER SEPARATOR '&')
FROM (SELECT @prime:=@prime + 1 AS PRIME_NUMBER
    FROM information_schema.tables
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prime:=1) r
    WHERE @num <1000
    ) p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT @divisor := @divisor + 1 AS DIVISOR FROM
    information_schema.tables 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @divisor:=1) r1
     WHERE @divisor <=1000
    ) d
WHERE MOD(PRIME_NUMBER, DIVISOR) = 0 AND PRIME_NUMBER != DIVISOR) ;
    enter code here
```

Explanation:

1. The two inner SELECTs (SELECT @prime and SELECT @divisor) create two lists. Both of them contain numbers from 1 to 1000. The first list is the "list of potential primes" and the second is the "list of divisors"
2. Then, we iterate over the list of the potential primes (the outer SELECT), and for each number from this list we look for divisors (SELECT * FROM clause) that can divide the number without a reminder and are not equal to the number (WHERE MOD... clause). If at least one such divisor exists, the number is not prime and is not selected (WHERE NOT EXISTS... clause).

Comment: What DBMS? Reading & assigning the same user variable in the same select statement is explicitly undefined in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (PrimeNumber INT)

DECLARE @final AS VARCHAR(1500)
SET @final = ''

DECLARE @counter INT
SET @counter = 2

WHILE @counter <= 1000
  BEGIN
      IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT primenumber
                     FROM   @table
                     WHERE  @counter % primenumber = 0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @table
            SELECT @counter

            SET @final = @final + Cast(@counter AS VARCHAR(20)) + '&'
        END

      SET @counter = @counter + 1
  END

SELECT Substring(@final, 0, Len(@final));
```